# 404 error when query string value starts with number

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In wordpress I have a custom template in my theme setup for accepting ajax calls. In the wordpress site I have a "page" setup (`page path = /ajax/`) to use that template - this gives me an endpoint for javascript to make requests to. In my javascript code I send `GET` requests to `/ajax/?param1=val1&param2=val2`, etc.

This works fine except in the case where the value of a parameter is a number. For instance: `/ajax/?param1=hello&**param2=12**`

In that instance the wordpress site throws a 404 error. It looks like wordpress doesn't map the url to the page when a parameter value is a number. This also happens when a parameter value starts with a number, so like `/ajax/?param1=hello&**param2=5foo**` does the same thing.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Using Wordpress 3.0.1

Edit: more info... This appears to be an environment issue. I only have this problem on my dev version of the site which is on dreamhost, but not on the live version of the site which is on 1and1.

dev php version: 5.3.27
live php version: 5.2.17 (doesn't have the parameter problem)

Comment: "Using Wordpress 3.0.1" Are you sure. You are about 4 years behind. Why don't you upgrade.

Comment: Which PHP version on your dev version ?

Comment: Maybe a bad rewriting rule ?

Comment: Could be related to this bug: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11917

Comment: @KevinLabécot I looked at the .htaccess file and it's basically the default wordpress rewrite rules.

Comment: In any case I'm moving the dev site over to the same hosting as the live site. Hopefully that will resolve the issue.

Comment: Wordpress has [builtin support for handling AJAX calls](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). Maybe you can circumvent the problem by using it instead of implementing your own AJAX handler.

Comment: Just to comment on my first comment, support for PHP 5.3 was dropped recently, PHP 5.2 has been dropped years back. Your question is clearly off topic as you are using outdated versions of wordpress and PHP. If you really want to carry on with dinosaurs, it is unfortunately your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to have nothing to do with the version of wordpress nor the version of php. One of my query string parameters was named "year", and when it contained a number, wordpress was matching that parameter up with the %year% token / parameter used to look up blog posts. The solution was to rename the parameter I was using to something else so it didn't conflict with the query string "year" param that wordpress uses internally.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For me the error was similar, but I had the `m` paramter, which - turned out - is also reserved. If the value started with a number, WordPress gave me a 404